# 52 commits behind master

Tags: git, bitbucket

I made some changes in my local repository and pushed those in the remote branch, when I created a Pull Request for the same, I noticed that the branch contains all the commits I have made against the master, going back to 3 months. I also got the message that I am "52 commits behind the master" which I am assuming is because my code is not merged with the master (Please let me know if I am wrong in this assumption). I wanted only the latest commit to go to the branch I have created. One of options I thought about was pushing the specific commit to a new branch and then create a PR for it against the master, but it seems all the commits will be pushed till the specific commit unless I change the order using `rebase`.

I wanted to know what would be the better option, sync the commits or change the order using `rebase` and then push only that specific commit to the local branch?

Any help would be appreciated
Note:I have recently started using git(bitbucket) and I'm struggling to grasp it and don't want to mess things up with the companies code, so there is a good chance that this question might not make sense.

I have tried to push the latest commit to the remote branch, but it seems to push all the commits till the latest commit. One of the option is to use `rebase`, but I am not really sure how I do it and whether it should be used.

Comment: so, did you create another branch or are you only working on master?

Comment: @VaTo, I have created a new branch and I am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. If you only want to push your commit to the master, 
The safest way is to use `cherry-pick` from your branch to the master. It's perfectly safe because you don't have to force-push.

1. Find the commit hash: `git log`.
2. Checkout to master: `git checkout master`.
3. Realign with master `git pull` or `git pull upstream master` if you're using upstream branch.
4. Check that you're aligned with master: `git status`.
5. Cherry pick without commit: `git cherry-pick -n <commit-hash>`
6. Commit: `git commit -m <commit message>`
7. Check the log, before pushing: `git log`. You can also check the diff: `git diff origin/master`.
8. Push to master: `git push`.

Comment: Hey @yahavi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried the same approach but it seems it still showing all the commits in the branch. I also tried to follow the bitbucket suggestion of "Sync now" where it asked me to run the command "git merge remotes/origin/master" and even after making the necessary changes, I am still getting all the commits in the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple rebase comment for updating your local repo,

**`git pull --rebase --autostash`**

Sometimes you will get merge conflicts, don't worry you can resolve that manually and use `git rebase --continue`

"*52 commits behind the master*" this because your local repository is not up-to-date.